# Integral of trigonometric function gives different answer

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, trigonometry

I am working on an integral on the following trigonometric functions

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\cos[(4m+2)x] \cos[(4m+1)x]}{\cos x}dx$$

where $m$ is positive integer. I am running the following code in mathematica

```
Assuming[Element[m, Integers] && (m > 0),
 Integrate[
  Cos[(4 m + 2) x] Cos[(4 m + 1) x]*1/Cos[x], {x, -π, π}]]
```

It gives me result of $\pi$. Since $m$ could be any positive number, I expect the integral should be $\pi$ if I replace $m$ with an integer before the integral. However, I got zero if I replace $m$ with number first.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  - I think there may be something more subtle going on here.  I get an error in evaluating this integral

Comment: @Mikado Okay, I'll withdraw my close vote. There are some overlapping issues with the `Assumptions`/`Assuming` posts that have come up in past, nd also with the `Assumptions->Element[something,Integers]` posts. But I see now that this also involves a singularity that the assumptions will not appropriately handle, so there are subtleties. And of course a memory exception is not an anticipated outcome here. (I have not seen that result yet, because my evaluation has been running for minutes with no outcome yet).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is very similar to that of [1] [How to compute the integral of trigonometic function with multiple angle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126984/how-to-compute-the-integral-of-trigonometic-function-with-multiple-angle)

Hence we don't repeat what we have discussed there but both answers should be read as complementary.

Let us focus here on the question of convergence of the integral.

The integrand is

```
g2[m_, x_] := Cos[(4 m + 2) x] Cos[(4 m + 1) x]*1/Cos[x];
```

The interesting values of `x` are those at which the `Cos[x]` becomes zero, i.e. at `x =  -π/2` and `x = + π/2`.

A series expansion about these points gives

```
Normal[Series[g2[m, x], {x, π/2, 0}]]

(* Out[184]= -Cos[2 m π]^2 - 4 m Cos[2 m π]^2 - (
 Cos[2 m π] Sin[2 m π])/(-(π/2) + x) + 2 Sin[2 m π]^2 + 
 4 m Sin[2 m π]^2 *)
```

For better visibility in LaTeX:

$$-\frac{\sin (2 \pi  m) \cos (2 \pi  m)}{x-\frac{\pi }{2}}+4 m \sin ^2(2 \pi  m)+2 \sin ^2(2 \pi  m)-4 m \cos ^2(2 \pi  m)-\cos ^2(2 \pi  m)$$

and

```
Normal[Series[g2[m, x], {x, -π/2, 0}]]

(* Out[185]= -Cos[2 m π]^2 - 4 m Cos[2 m π]^2 + (
 Cos[2 m π] Sin[2 m π])/(π/2 + x) + 2 Sin[2 m π]^2 + 
 4 m Sin[2 m π]^2 *)
```

LaTeX:

$$\frac{\sin (2 \pi  m) \cos (2 \pi  m)}{x+\frac{\pi }{2}}+4 m \sin ^2(2 \pi  m)+2 \sin ^2(2 \pi  m)-4 m \cos ^2(2 \pi  m)-\cos ^2(2 \pi  m)$$

These expressions remain finite if the numerator

```
num2 = Cos[2 m π] Sin[2 m π];
```

of the pole is zero.

This means

```
Simplify[num2]

(* Out[187]= 1/2 Sin[4 m π] *)

Reduce[% == 0, m] /. C[1] -> n

(* Out[188]= n ∈ Integers && (m == n/2 || m == (π + 2 n π)/(4 π)) *)
```

Which means that `m` must be of the form `m = n/4` with `n` integer.

The integral of the OP is

```
f2[m_] := Integrate[g2[m, x], {x, -π, π}]
```

The first few values are

```
Table[{m/4, f2[m/4]}, {m, -5, 5}]

(* Out[195]= {{-(5/4), 0}, {-1, 2 π}, {-(3/4), 0}, {-(1/2), 2 π}, {-(1/4), 
  2 π}, {0, 0}, {1/4, 2 π}, {1/2, 0}, {3/4, 2 π}, {1, 0}, {5/4, 
  2 π}} *)
```

For values of `m` which are not integer multiples of 1/4 the integral is divergent.

For the OP [1] the convergence condition is `m = n/2`, `n` integer.

Comment: @ Dr. WolfangHintze : Something to adjust because of  $\sin(2\pi m)=0$ for each integer $m.$

Comment: Integer multiples of quarters include halfs and integers.

Comment: @ Dr. Wolfang Hintze : Sorry, don't understand it. Look at the formula under " For better visibility is LaTeX " in your answer.

Comment: Also Assuming[Element[m, Integers] && (m > 0), 
 Limit[Cos[(4 m + 2) x] Cos[(4 m + 1) x]*1/Cos[x], x -> Pi/2]] ouputs -1-4m.

Comment: Thanks all. It makes sense to expand the integrand to figure the singularities. I just wonder why mathematica will directly given the answer $2\pi$ without considering the divergence. In what assumption mathematica makes to give that result.

Comment: "I just wonder why mathematica will directly given the answer 2π 
 without considering the divergence. In what assumption mathematica makes to give that result" No assumptons is necessary any more because the value of m is inserted into the integrand before the integral is done, and there is not singularity any more in the integrand.

Comment: @ Dr. Wolfgang Hintze: Mathematica 11 fails with it, outputting nothing.

Comment: (at)user64494 what do you get if you calculate f2 above in version 11? You can add your result to my post, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #2: proof**

Here's the missing proof that the integral

$$f(\text{m})=\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } \sec (x) \cos ((4 m+1) x) \cos ((4 m+2) x) \, dx$$

is zero for m = 0, 1, 2, ...

Following the idea of Yarchik in [How to compute the integral of trigonometic function with multiple angle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126984/how-to-compute-the-integral-of-trigonometic-function-with-multiple-angle/126995#126995)
we observe that the integrand can be represented as the finite sum

```
s = -Sum[(-1)^n Cos[2 n (x)], {n, 1, 4 m + 1}];
```

Indeed

```
FullSimplify[s == Cos[x (4 m + 1)] Cos[x (4 m + 2)] Sec[x], m ∈ Integers]

(* True *)
```

Now the integral over `s` can be done for each summand separately which is

```
Integrate[Cos[2 n x], {x, -π, π}]
Simplify[%, {n ∈ Integers, n > 0}]

(* Out[288]= Sin[2 n π]/n *)

(* Out[289]= 0 *)
```

Now a finite sum of zeroes is zero. Hence the integral over s is zero and so is the original integral. QED.

*Remark*

Examples of finite sums over trigonometric functions of the type discussed here can be found in Gradshteyn/Ryshik 1.341

Comment: Gradshteyn&Ryzhik 1.341 does not include the formula suggested by Yarchik (see https://www.dropbox.com/s/5p6cpdetf9l3mtf/screen26.09.16.docx?dl=0 )

Comment: Yes, you are right, this example is not contained in GR. That's is why I provided it after some playing around with the sum in Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

When I execute the code, I get an error.  Have we found some sort of bug?

```
$Version
Assuming[Element[m, Integers] && (m > 0), 
 Integrate[
  Cos[(4 m + 2) x] Cos[(4 m + 1) x]*1/Cos[x], {x, -π, π}]]
(* "11.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)" *)
```

> ```
> (* Throw::sysexc: Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[…, _SystemException]. *)
> ```

```
(* SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"] *)
```

Comment: Maybe. A memory exception is certainly not what one would anticipate here.